# The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened - Docker & Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to set the permissions of my test webpage to run injunction with my nginx container. When I execute:

```
$ docker exec test_site_app php artisan storage:link
```

I get this permission error:

> The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

When I execute a `$ docker exec test_site_app ls -la` command on my app, I see that the permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       4096 Dec 11 07:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    220 Jan 20 00:33 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    829 Jan 20 00:33 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    811 Jan 20 00:33 .env.example
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    111 Jan 20 00:33 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    191 Jan 20 00:33 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    181 Jan 20 00:33 .styleci.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   7133 Jan 20 00:33 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   3780 Jan 20 00:33 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   1686 Jan 20 00:33 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   1646 Jan 20 00:33 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 267526 Jan 20 00:33 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 database
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 mysql
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    473 Jan 20 00:33 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   1202 Jan 20 00:33 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 public
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 routes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    563 Jan 20 00:33 server.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 storage
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 tests
drwxr-xr-x 44 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 20 00:33 vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    559 Jan 20 00:33 webpack.mix.js
```

However, when I run `whoami` on each container (app and nginx) I see this:

```
$ docker exec test_site_app whoami
www
$ docker exec test_site_nginx whoami
root
```

I specifically created the user `www` in my app within my Dockerfile:

```
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

COPY . /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

USER www
```

However, my Nginx uses `nobody` within the `nginx.conf` because if I try to use `www-data` I get this error:

> getpwnam("www-data") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 nginx: [emerg]
> getpwnam("www-data") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

So already here I can see the permission issues but I really am not sure how to fix this. All of my Laravel files are `chown -R www-data:www-data` before I run `$ docker-compose up --build -d`.

**[To create my environment, here are my configurations](https://gist.github.com/Jaquarh/a0c9b33e106d0d1960ef82319dd33abc)** hosted via Gist.

How can I fix this permission issue?